# Git Graph not displaying information

Tags: git

Basically, the extension showed the following error:

[image]

I had git installed correctly and it was working find on terminal

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, this problem happened because I had **two Github users configured** with ssh in my machine and there were some default configurations messing everything up.

First, you need to find your global configuration file and delete everything inside. In my cased I had the following

> user.name=user1
> user.email=user1@gmail.com

Now open a new project

Then, go to gitGraph repository settings (top right engine on Git Graph tab). Edit "User Details", delete User Name and User Email and disable "Use Globally".

[image]

After this is done you can initialize git (git init) and before the first commit you will need to configure the user and email with:

> git config user.name 'example'

> git config user.email 'example@example.com'

Now GitGraph should work properly. You will need to enter your git user and email in every repositoy, this is the only way i found to not confused the extension.

Just as a reminder: If you have a global user (user1) in the global config git file and then in your repo you have (user2) as the defaults of GitGraph or you initialize git with user2 credentials having user1 in the global config git file things will not work